# How to make a pyramid like this?

Tags: modeling, mesh

the left is mine, how to make the right one?
[image]

Comment: The answer by @moonboots shows the right solution, but I'm curious: how did you get your result? Did you first flatten or bevel the top somehow separately before the corners?

Comment: The left one has a face on top, I merged top 4 vertices and get the right one, there was no bottom face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with a simple 5 face pyramid and bevel seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: Looks like OP has the bottom face extruded a bit, does this throw off the bevel operation?

Comment: @moonboots "Delete the bottom face, bevel, then fill the bottom?" Why not just not bevel the bottom edge? And what I would do because I somehow don't like the little "bulging up" in the corners (but it's in the original question's image, so it's only bothering me), I would first bevel the quadratic loop around and then the diagonals going across the top.

Comment: I am not sure if the base is bevelled (from the picture shown), that's all ;)

Comment: @moonboots What I meant was if you don't want to bevel the bottom edge (it looks like it's not), why delete a face and add it afterwards? If you simply don't select the bottom edge it will not be beveled when you bevel the rest of them.

Comment: oh yes you must be right, I don't remember why I said that